# What's the reasoning behind these approaches to git-based code deployment?

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment

So, I enjoy using git as a tool for deploying web application code to the production space from my development space, but I'm admittedly new to it and not especially knowledgeable. I was wondering if anyone could clarify for me why it is that I see people explicitly advocating these two opposed models of git-based deployment?

1. Create the master repository in your development environment and branch to production.
2. Create the master repository in your production environment and branch to development.

As a solo developer (or as a newbie), I'm not seeing what the real, functional difference between the two is. What are the advantages and disadvantages of either approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out [Source Control Done Right](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Source-Control-Done-Right.aspx), it doesn't specifically discuss the concept of git (more a fundamental), but it does explain the two patterns of Branch by Exception and Branch by Release -- which these workflows *almost* want to accomplish.